# multiple file upload with maximum size in yii2

Tags: post, yii2

i am trying to upload multiple file at once,
my max_upload_size = 20 it works fine for total post size less than 20MB

> [['fileUpload'], 'file','maxFiles' => 6]

but when i upload file greter than 20MB it shows me error message

i also handel exception in controller , but program execution not entring in controolers action
help me to solve this problem[image]

Comment: you need to change your php ini settings to increase `max_upload_size`, `max_execution_time` and restart your webserver

Answer (score 2):

You have to change following settings in php.ini file

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 80M // set this as per your requirement  

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 80M // // set this as per your requirement

max_execution_time = 60 // time is in seconds
```

After modifying you need to restart your HTTP server to use apply configuration.

Comment: Adding to it : Yii2 Project Folder Also Having Their Own php.ini file. You can look there too.

Comment: i had alredy set upload_max_filesize = 20M, post_max_size = 20M,max_execution_time = 6000 as per my requirment, it works fine for filesize upto 20MB , but i need to handel exception occure when i upload file with size gretter than 20MB

Comment: do you want to restrict user from uploading files larger than 20 MB ? if yes, then you need to apply some validation rules